# How to add an entry in vertex with datatype of value Set in gremlin

Tags: java, groovy, gremlin, titan, graphdb

I have tried below query

```
g.V(12345678).property("names",["Akshay"] as List)
```

It worked fine in my case. But I want value datatype to be a Set. Hence I tried below query.

```
g.V(12345678).property("names",["Akshay"] as Set)
```

But exception like this

```
Property value [[Akshay]] is of type class java.util.LinkedHashSet is not supported Display stack trace? [yN] n
```

Please tell me a way to save value datatype as Set

Answer (score 0):

Values need to be added one by one. If you only need to add one value, it's pretty easy:

```
g.V(12345678).property(set,"names","Akshay")
```

If you have a set of values to add, you can do something like this:

```
g.V(12345678).as("v").
  constant(["Akshay","Daniel"]).unfold().as("n").
  select("v").
    property(set,"names",select("n"))
```

Comment: compilation error unexpected token any other better approach as the values will be dynamic